# Druid TopNMetricSpec - Performance Clarification

Tags: druid

Problem statement:
I need to find all the distinct userIDs from huge dataset (~100Millions) and so experimenting with TopNMetricSpec so that I get userIDs based on the set threshold.

Can you anyone help me to understand how TopNMetricSpec runs?

If I run following TopN query with TopNMetricSpec repeatedly for 'n' times using the same http client,
then I want to know will this scan all the records every time when we set previousStop.

Consider the following Data:

```
┌──────────────────────────┬─────────┬────────┬────────┐
│ __time                   │ movieId │ rating │ userId │
├──────────────────────────┼─────────┼────────┼────────┤
│ 2015-02-05T00:10:09.000Z │ 2011    │ 3.5    │ 215    │
│ 2015-02-05T00:10:26.000Z │ 38061   │ 3.5    │ 215    │
│ 2015-02-05T00:10:32.000Z │ 8981    │ 2.0    │ 215    │
│ 2015-02-05T00:11:00.000Z │ 89864   │ 4.0    │ 215    │
│ 2015-02-23T23:55:08.000Z │ 56587   │ 1.5    │ 31     │
│ 2015-02-23T23:55:33.000Z │ 51077   │ 4.0    │ 31     │
│ 2015-02-23T23:55:35.000Z │ 49274   │ 4.0    │ 31     │
│ 2015-02-23T23:55:37.000Z │ 30816   │ 2.0    │ 31     
│ 2015-03-19T14:24:01.000Z │ 5066    │ 5.0    │ 176    │
│ 2015-03-19T14:26:23.000Z │ 6776    │ 5.0    │ 176    │
│ 2015-03-29T16:19:58.000Z │ 2337    │ 2.0    │ 96     │
```

For example, in the following query:

1. Initially, I have set previous stop as null and threshold has two so it will fetch first two records (because threshold = 2) viz. 215, 176
2. Now, I will pass previous stop = 176 now the question is will the broker scan all the records again or will it just scan from where it stopped after step 1 i.e. 176?

   ```
   {
      "queryType": "topN",
      "dataSource": "ratings30K",
      "intervals": "2015-02-05T00:00:00.000Z/2015-03-30T00:00:00.000Z",
      "granularity": "all",
      "dimension":"userId",
      "threshold": 2,
      "metric": {
       "type": "inverted",
       "metric": {
           "type": "dimension",
           "ordering": "Numeric",
           "previousStop": null
          }
      }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't quite work the way you describe it.  You have two options as to what to give as `metric` in this query.  You can either find the users that have given the highest ratings:

```
"dimension":"userId",
"metric":"rating"
```

Or you can sort by user id in ascending order, in which case you can provide a `previousStop`:

```
"dimension":"userId",
"metric": {
    "type": "dimension",
    "ordering": "Numeric",
    "previousStop": null
}
```

<sup>(For either of those two options, you can invert the sort order by wrapping the metric in an inverted metric spec.)</sup>

But when you sort by `rating`, you can't give a `previousStop` value.  So if you want pagination that is guaranteed to return all rows, you can't sort by rating.

Comment: So if I plan to go with the second approach, the problem is I have like millions of userIds I need to fetch (~50 million), so if I try to fetch all at once, it won't be able to fit in my memory (jvm), so I need to use some mechanism like (threshold and previousStop in topN), but going through the documentation and after some research,  I found out that the topN query will scan for all the records every time even if it wants to return a chunk of those to me. This will be a performance degradation because I am unnecessary scanning all the userIds every time